# In KUSTO find the not empty columns out of 3 candidates and extend as new column

Tags: azure, azureportal, kql

I want for each entry/line look up if my information (criteria not empty) is in NAME1, NAME2 or NAME3.

I want do find a shorter and more elegant way than a double nested iff:

```
.....
|extend name= iff(isempty(NAME1) == false,  NAME1,  iff(isempty(NAME2) == false,  NAME2, NAME3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you meant `isnotempty()` and not `isempty()`, then you could use the `coalesce()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction

for example - the value under the column `d` in the result of the following query is `'hello'`

```
print a = '', b = '', c = 'hello'
| project d = coalesce(a, b, c)
```

Comment: actually by ```isempty(NAME1) == false``` I want columns which are not empty